# HTML/CSS/JavaScipt and Email Configuration with PHP. Email not sending? Only prompts button as "Sending..." and then nothing happens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, xampp

I am trying to send an email with PHP, but it isn't working. I think my code is correct, but I am having troubles connecting to the back-end server from my iMac computer. The form just says "Sending..." and I get no email.

What I tried:

- Downloaded XAMPP and put the whole code in the `htdocs` folder.
- Followed the prompts and installed packages to "Send Email with PHP" on the XAMPP website.
- Downloaded Node.js and Express.
- Tried to put file in localhost directory (not working). This is where it is located: `file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/constructioncompany-master/public/index.html`
- Tried to click "Send" button and check the console.log simultaneously, and nothing happens. It's still loading with "Sending"
- Checked my spam email inbox to see if it sent there.
- Checked the error log in XAMPP and it says this, but not sure if this is relevant (I am new with PHP):

`[Sun Jan 29 19:11:11.379312 2023] [php:error] [pid 64583] [client ::1:55351] script '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/contact_process.php' not found or unable to stat`

**contact.html**

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h2 class="contact-title">SEND US A MESSAGE</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <form class="form-contact contact_form" action="contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" placeholder="Enter your name" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your email'" placeholder="Enter your email" required="'">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter subject'" placeholder="Enter subject" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="9" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write your message'" placeholder="Write your message" required=""></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                                <button type="submit" id="send" class="button boxed-btn">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
                        <div class="media contact-info">
                            <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-home"></i></span>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h3>San Francisco, CA, USA</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media contact-info">
                            <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-tablet"></i></span>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h3>828-450-2288</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media contact-info">
                            <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-email"></i></span>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h3>handtfloors@gmail.com</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media contact-info">
                            <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-facebook"></i></span>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/SanFranciscoFloors">@SanFranciscoFloors</a></li>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media contact-info">
                            <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-instagram"></i></span>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/handtflooring/?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y%3D">@handtflooring</a></li>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php
    

    class Sendmail{
        
    function getMailStatus(){
        //Check For Submit
            $status = '';
            //Get Form Data
            $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
            $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
            $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
            $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
            $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
    
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
                    $status = '3';
                } else {
                    // Passed
                    // Recipient Email
                    $toEmail = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';
                    $subject = ''.$title;
                    $body = '<h2>H & T Flooring Contact Request</h2>
                        <h4>Name</h4><p>'.$name.'</p>
                        <h4>Phone Number</h4><p>'.$phone.'</p>
                        <h4>Email</h4><p>'.$email.'</p>
                        <h4>Message</h4><p>'.$message.'</p>
                        ';
    
                    //Email Headers
                    $headers ="MIME-Version: 1.0" ."\r\n";
                    $headers .="Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    
                    // Additional Headers
                    $headers .= "From: " .$name. "<".$email.">". "\r\n";
    
                    if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $headers)){
                        // Email Sent
                        $status = '1';
                    } else {
                        //Failed
                        $status = '2';
                    }
                }
            
        return $status;
    }
        
    }
            
    $test = new Sendmail();
        echo $test->getMailStatus();
    ?>
```

**contact.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#send").on('click', function(e){
        
        $("#send").text('Sending...');
        $("#send").attr('disabled', true);
        
        $.ajax({
                url: "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/constructioncompany-master/public/contact_process.php",
            method:"POST",
                dataType:"JSON",
                data:{
                    name:$("#name").val(),
                    email:$("#email").val(),
                    phone:$("#phone").val(),
                    subject:$("#subject").val(),
                    message:$("#message").val()
                },
                success:function(res){
                    $("#send").text('Send');
                    $("#send").attr('disabled', false);
                    if (res == 1){
                        $("#status").html('Message Sent Successfully! Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you as soon as possible.');
                    }else if(res == 0){
                        $("#status").html('Message Failed.');
                    }else if(res == 2){
                        $("#status").html('Empty Fields Detected.');
                    }else if(res == 3){
                        $("#status").html('Invalid Email Address.');
                    }
                    
                },
                error: function(err){
                    
                    $('#status').html( "Network Connection Error.");
                }
                });
    
        
    });
    
    });
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on localhost3000");
});
```

Comment: The PHP Error suggests your Form is posting to the wrong location. I would think it would be relative to the page running it. I would try just posting to `contact_process.php` instead, to start.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between a file system path, and a URL? Typically, your `localhost` would have its web root set to `/.../XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/`. And that means, your AJAX request should go to `/constructioncompany-master/public/contact_process.php` here.

Comment: The lack of a `To:` header and the missing space before `<` in the `From:` header could also trip some checks; many spammers, like you, just guess what needs to go in the email headers, and so some spam filters will also react on these types of errors.